# How I can Create a timer component in Blazor and start it from outside of component or other page

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

How  I can Create a timer component in Blazor and start it from outside of component or other page.
My component code is as below:

```
@using LosacoWeb.Shared.Enumes
@using System.Timers
@implements IDisposable

@if (BlnVisiblaState == true)
{
    <section>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
                    <div>

                        <div class="alert shortcode_modules" style="border-color:lightblue;border-style: solid;border-width: thin;padding: 5px;margin: 5px 10px;border-radius: 5px;" role="alert">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="modules__title">
                                <h3 dir="rtl" style="float:right;">@MessageTitle</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modules__content">
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.primary)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.secondary)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.success)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.info)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.warning)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                                @if (message == MessagePanelColor.danger)
                                {
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        <strong>@MessageShortDescription !!!</strong>@MessageBuddyLongDescription
                                        @*<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                            </button>*@
                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end .col-md-6 -->
                </div>
                <!-- end .row -->
            </div>
            <!-- end .container -->
        </div>
    </section>
}
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public Boolean BlnVisiblaState { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public String MessageTitle { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public String MessageShortDescription { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public String MessageBuddyLongDescription { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public LosacoWeb.Shared.Enumes.MessagePanelColor message { get; set; }

    Timer timer;
    int int_Counter = 0;

    public async Task ChangeState()
    {
        BlnVisiblaState = !BlnVisiblaState;
        timer.Stop();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public async Task StasrtTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Elapsed += TimerOnElapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerOnElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (int_Counter >= 5)
        {
            ChangeState();
            //Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        int_Counter++;
        Console.WriteLine(int_Counter.ToString());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how I can start and stop the timer from other Blazor pages. this page should show a massage and it hide after 6 seconds. but I can not start timer from outer pages. thanks for your attention.

Comment: As a side note you could change `class="alert alert-danger"` to `class="alert alert-@message"`  and remove all those `@if` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually create a timer component as you post in the question title.
What you actually want is to create a service class which you can inject into your components. You can do that in various ways, and provide whatever functionality you want.

Your timer service class may look something like this (`Warning you should also implement the IDisposable interface to dispose the timer in order to prevent memory leaks`):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

public class BlazorTimer
    {
        private Timer _timer;
        private int count;
        private int end;
        internal void SetTimer(double interval, int start, int _end)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(interval);
            _timer.Elapsed += Counter;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
            count = start;
            end = _end;
            _timer.Start();
        }
        
        private void Counter(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            if (count >= end)
            {
                ((Timer)sender).Stop();
                TimerEventArgs args = new TimerEventArgs { Count = count };
                OnCountCompleted(args);
            }
        }
        

        protected virtual void OnCountCompleted(TimerEventArgs args)
        {
            EventHandler<TimerEventArgs> handler = CountCompleted;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<TimerEventArgs> CountCompleted;
    }
    
    public class TimerEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
```

### Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

           //...Code removed for brevity's sake...

            builder.Services.AddScoped(config =>
            {
                var blazorTimer = new BlazorTimer();
                blazorTimer.SetTimer(1000, 100, 110);
                return blazorTimer;
            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

### Usage

```
@page "/counter"

@inject BlazorTimer Timer
@implements IDisposable

<h1>Counter</h1>
    @count.ToString()

    <p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

    @code {
        private int currentCount = 0;

        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }

protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
          
            Timer.CountCompleted += NotifyCompleted;

            base.OnInitialized();
        }


        int count = 0;
        private void NotifyCompleted(object sender, TimerEventArgs args)
        {

            count = args.Count;
            InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
        }


        public void Dispose()
        {
            Timer.CountCompleted -= NotifyCompleted;
        }
    }
```

Note: As I've previously said, you can code in various ways, as for instance, you don't necessarily have to set the values of the interval, start and end when your Timer is injected (Main method), you can code it to get these values from your components in the OnInitialised(Async) method pair.

Comment: I haven't needed / tried to make a timer service yet, but this looks pretty juicy!

Comment: Thanks. I add your class and your code to my Blazor project. but any things does not happened. Please guide me.

Comment: I'd suggest you first to create a new WebAssembly App, replace the code in the Counter component with that posted by me, and then see if it works for you, and only then try to incorporate it into your old application. If you don't succeed you may upload your app to github, so I can inspect it.